# Convert byte to fileinputstream

Tags: java, android, encryption, parse-platform

is there a way i can convert my byte file into fileinputstream so i can decrypt it before i convert it to bitmap. i have tried to change it to fileinputstream and then again but it doesn't seem to work.

```
 ParseFile fileObject = (ParseFile) object.get("ImageFile");fileObject.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {

    public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
         if (e == null) {
          Log.d("test",
          "We've got data in data.");
           FileInputStream data1 = new FileInputStream(data);
           // Decode the Byte[] into 
          // Bitmap
           Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decrypt(key, data), 0, data.length);
          // Get the ImageView from
          // main.xml
           ImageView imgFile = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

           // Set the Bitmap into the
           // ImageView
           imgFile.setImageBitmap(bmp);

          // Close progress dialog
           progressDialog.dismiss();
```

my decrypt class takes byte and fileinputstream as parameters

private byte[] decrypt(byte[] skey, FileInputStream fis){

```
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(skey, "AES");
    Cipher cipher;
    byte[] decryptedData=null;
    CipherInputStream cis=null;
    try {
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
        // Create CipherInputStream to read and decrypt the image data
        cis = new CipherInputStream(fis, cipher);
        // Write encrypted image data to ByteArrayOutputStream
        ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] data = new byte[2048];
        while ((cis.read(data)) != -1) {
            buffer.write(data);
        }
        buffer.flush();
        decryptedData=buffer.toByteArray();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        try {
            fis.close();
            cis.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return decryptedData;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be asking about this:

```
public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
   ...
   FileInputStream data1 = new FileInputStream(data);
```

which (clearly) won't compile.  If you really want to open a `FileInputStream` for data in a byte array, you need to write the data to a (temporary) file in the file system and then create a `FileInputStream` for that file.  That is cumbersome.

A better idea would be to change

```
private byte[] decrypt(byte[] skey, FileInputStream fis) {
```

to

```
private byte[] decrypt(byte[] skey, InputStream fis) {
```

Then open a `ByteArrayInputStream` onto your `data1` array and pass that to `decrypt`.

Comment: isn't parse passing the file as byte ? so how come i can't just pass it to decrypt!

Comment: Because ... you have defined your `decrypt` method so that won't work!  If you changed your `decrypt` method to take the data as a `byte[]`, then you *could* pass the data as a `byte[]`.  But then you would need to create a ByteArrayInputStream inside the `decrypt` method ... because `CipherInputStream` must be instantiated with an `InputStream` of some kind.